# Parse checking if nil

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have some code that pulls users based on what they type on a login view. I am trying to check if a specific field is blank (nil) with something along the following

```
for user in users{
   if user["secretkey"] == nil {
   query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(user.objectId) {
```

However, when the column "secretkey" is in fact nil, tested with println(user["secretkey"], the if statement continues to its default.

Answer (score 2):

Use the form:

```
for user in users {
    if let secretKey = user["secretkey"] {
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(user.objectId) {
    }
}
```

(you can also then use `secretKey` directly inside the `if` block if you wanted to)

Comment: Sorry, I thought this got it earlier, but all this does is set the value. I need to check if the value is nil in parse. It is a licensing system. If the key isn't existent or matches, it needs to allow the user access, and if nil it needs to set the key. If it is existent and does not match, it shows an alert.

Comment: If this is an access control issue you should consider using cloud code to hold the logic to reduce hacking issues and circumvention. Cloud code can inspect the user and decide what to return.

Comment: I am looking into that, however why would I receive the error as I am above?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it in my situation by declaring it as a variable first using the following.

```
let secretKeyParse = user["secretkey"] as String?
              if secretKeyParse == nil {
```